# Can't seem to find penny lane module error fix

Tags: python

```
/Users/rityarch/model/LSTM/Draft 3.ipynb Cell 19 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from Factory import SequenceDataset

File ~/model/LSTM/Factory.py:4, in <module>
      2 from torch import nn
      3 from torch.utils.data import Dataset
----> 4 import pennylane as qml
      6 class SequenceDataset(Dataset):
      7     def __init__(self, dataframe, target, features, sequence_length=5):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pennylane'/Users/rityarch/model/LSTM/Draft 3.ipynb Cell 19 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from Factory import SequenceDataset

File ~/model/LSTM/Factory.py:4, in <module>
      2 from torch import nn
      3 from torch.utils.data import Dataset
----> 4 import pennylane as qml
      6 class SequenceDataset(Dataset):
      7     def __init__(self, dataframe, target, features, sequence_length=5):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pennylane'
```

Comment: Have you done `$ pip install PennyLane`?

Comment: if you installed `PennyLane` then maybe you have two Pythons and `pip` install in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules. It may need to use ie. `pip3` (or `pip3.9`, `pip3.10`,etc.) instead of `pip` . Eventually it needs `python -m pip install ...`